# not returning stubbed value in the mockito,its all empty

Tags: mockito, powermockito

Actual code:

```
RegistrationData registrationData = (RegistrationData)xstream.fromXML(text);
```

Mocked class:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(XStream.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockXStream);

when(mockXStream.fromXML(any(String.class))).thenReturn(RegistrationData.class);
```

Not sure what I am missing , not getting any error, only returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean:

```
when(mockXStream.fromXML(any(String.class))).thenReturn(mock(RegistrationData.class));
```

You don't want to return a `Class` object, you want to return a mock, right?